# Python Django manage.py runserver too many values to unpack Passing a 3-tuple to include() is not supported

Tags: python, django

Trying to run

python manage.py runserver on a virtual environment with a practically new django project

but then getting this long error

```
(venv) ugps-MacBook-4:mysite gust$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10d09b268>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gust/GoogleDrive/code/python/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 17, in include
    urlconf_module, app_name = arg
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gust/GoogleDrive/code/python/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gust/GoogleDrive/code/python/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/gust/GoogleDrive/code/python/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/gust/GoogleDrive/code/python/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/gust/GoogleDrive/code/python/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/gust/GoogleDrive/code/python/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/Users/gust/GoogleDrive/code/python/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/Users/gust/GoogleDrive/code/python/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/gust/GoogleDrive/code/python/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 536, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/gust/GoogleDrive/code/python/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/gust/GoogleDrive/code/python/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 529, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Users/gust/GoogleDrive/code/python/django/venv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/gust/GoogleDrive/code/python/django/mysite/mysite/urls.py", line 9, in <module>
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  File "/Users/gust/GoogleDrive/code/python/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 27, in include
    'provide the namespace argument to include() instead.' % len(arg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Passing a 3-tuple to include() is not supported. Pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name, and provide the namespace argument to include() instead.
```

my python,django and pip versions are
python 3.6.4
(2,0,4,'final',0)
pip 10.0.1

using mac os high sierra which had a native python version of 2.7 but that shouldn't be a problem since i'm using a virtual env

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Changed in Django 1.9:
In previous versions, you would pass `admin.site.urls` to include().
The properly way to add `django admin app` is

```
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: ah i see, i wonder where i made the mistake of making django generate the mismatching code between versions, i would think the default generated code would be correct

Comment: Perhaps you ran `manage.py startproject` before you activated the virtual environment. Django 2.0 wouldn’t generate a file with `include(admin.site.urls)`.